# Unmarshalling XML from result of xml.Marshal()

Tags: xml, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a small `struct` which I want to marshal and unmarshal using the [`encoding/xml`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) package:

```
type Point struct {
    X, Y  int
    z     int // unexported
    Names []string
}
```

The encoding/decoding works fine when I use the [`encoding/json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package.

But when I use the `encoding/xml` package, only the `xml.Marshal()` works, the `xml.Unmarshal()` returns an error:

```
invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

**This is how I do it for XML:**

```
p := Point{1, 2, 3, []string{"Bob", "Alice"}}
data, err := xml.Marshal(p)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}
fmt.Println("XML:", string(data))

var pXml Point
err = json.Unmarshal(data, &pXml)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}
fmt.Println("Unmarshalled XML:", pXml)
```

Why do I get this error and how can I unmarshal the XML output returned by `xml.Marshal()`?

Here is the complete, runnable application on the [**Go Playground**](http://play.golang.org/p/5dE4NCB1HO) to try out.

**Output of the application:**

```
Input: {1 2 3 [Bob Alice]}
JSON: {"X":1,"Y":2,"Names":["Bob","Alice"]}
Unmarshalled JSON: {1 2 0 [Bob Alice]}

XML: <Point><X>1</X><Y>2</Y><Names>Bob</Names><Names>Alice</Names></Point>
Error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Unmarshalled XML: {0 0 0 []}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to unmarshal XML as if it's JSON. First you do

```
data, err := xml.Marshal(p)
```

and then

```
err = json.Unmarshal(data, &pXml)
```

Line 46 in your code should be

```
err = xml.Unmarshal(data, &pXml)
```

Comment: Omg, such a trivial mistake and I couldn't find it. Thanks.